# Very basic: "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
x = 2
```

`print “This application is running okay if 2 + 2 = #{x + x}”`

This is the error message I get

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
print “This application is running okay if 2 + 2 = #{x + x}”
                                                ^
```

I can't seem to find my own error here. I'm running Ruby 2.0.0 on OS X 10.10 using TextEdit to write the code. Help is appreciated

Comment: Are you aware of the strange double quotes you're using?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. My machine's keyboard layout is in another language and I changed it to English. I better fix those keys now

Comment: FIXED: on TextEdit, Edit-Substitutions-uncheck Smart Quotes. The TextEdit application was automatically changing my quotes. It had nothing to do with the Keyboard layout having been changed to English. Thanks again

Comment: By the way: even the *extremely* basic syntax highlighting of StackOverflow catches this, as you can see in your question.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I didn't catch the mistake. I didn't see the syntax highlighted until after I posted the question. Thanks for pointing it out though

Answer (score 5):

The code is correct. In fact, here's the ouput on my machine.

```
2.1.5 :001 > x = 2
 => 2
2.1.5 :002 > print "This application is running okay if 2 + 2 = #{x + x}"
This application is running okay if 2 + 2 = 4 => nil
```

A possible explanation is a syntax error caused by the use of "curly quotes" `”` in your code, rather than the standard quote `"`.

```
print “This application is running okay if 2 + 2 = #{x + x}”
```

This is a special character that will not be interpreted as a string opener and could cause your script to fail.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. My machine's keyboard layout is in another language and I changed it to English. I better fix those keys now

Comment: FIXED: on TextEdit, Edit-Substitutions-uncheck Smart Quotes. The TextEdit application was automatically changing my quotes. It had nothing to do with the Keyboard layout having been changed to English. Thanks again

Comment: Do not use TextEdit to write code. TextEdit is not a text code editor, is a document editor. It applies formatting and other fancy things to the text you are writing. To code you need a plain text editor (such as Textmate, Sublime Editor, etc).

Comment: I was just playing around with the machine I just received and hadn't downloaded Atom. I was also trying to locate the keys in English because the keyboard layout is in a different language and wrote the code to do a quick run on it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using some unusual double quote character (” instead of "), so the argument to the print statement is not being interpreted as a string.  The quotes you are using are probably unicode [U+201C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) and [U+201D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm). This indicates you are editing your code in a typographic quotes mode (or Unicode mode) on your text editor - try switching it to ASCII mode to edit source files.

See this [Ruby Fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/ff3b1) - the statement works OK with the proper double quotes.  If you uncomment your version, you'll get the syntax error you report.

***EDIT***

As per OP - the auto-changing of quotes in TextEdit was fixed by:

> on TextEdit, Edit-Substitutions-uncheck Smart Quotes. The TextEdit application was automatically changing my quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. My machine's keyboard layout is in another language and I changed it to English. I better fix those keys now

Comment: FIXED: on TextEdit, Edit-Substitutions-uncheck Smart Quotes. The TextEdit application was automatically changing my quotes. It had nothing to do with the Keyboard layout having been changed to English. Thanks again

Comment: No problem - I'll edit it into the answer and you can accept so it's preserved for anyone else with same issue (comments are not guaranteed to hang around)